# What are some algorithms & data structures useful for aligning (financial) asynchronous systems?

Tags: python, pandas, financial

I'm auditing some financial data between two transaction systems. The two datasets consist of lists of transactions. Each has,

- timestamp,
- idiosyncratic transaction IDs (not shared between systems)
- transaction values (item names, item values, totals, adjustments).

The data is imperfect; 10-20% of the data doesn't align well.

I've cobbled together a solution to the problem using Pandas: [What's a more efficient way to merge rows from DataFrames row-by-row with conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42615702/whats-a-more-efficient-way-to-merge-rows-from-dataframes-row-by-row-with-condit). 
A simple `pandas.merge()` is too greedy and produces many erroneous matches. A good match is on several criteria across the dataset.

**What are some alternatives to using Pandas?**
As I researched the problem, I found some Pandas answers suggest operations which cause me to be concerned about dropped data or duplication.

To put it into the form of a better Stackoverflow question: **What are some popular algorithms or data structures useful for matching activity between two separate systems?**

- Something that doesn't mutate the original dataset,
- won't drop items from the original dataset,
- works with the assumption each entry has a match which is either present or missing from the other datasets

Comment: `merge_asof()` does a merge on "close" matches, and can either match to the nearest greater or less than.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Aligning financial asynchronous systems involves handling data that may not be synchronized in real-time. Several algorithms and data structures can be useful for this purpose:

1. **Timestamps and Event Sourcing:**

   - Use timestamps to order events in a time series.
   - Implement event sourcing to capture all changes as a sequence of events, facilitating synchronization.
2. **Distributed Ledger Technology (DLT) / Blockchain:**

   - Leverage blockchain for a decentralized and distributed ledger that ensures consistency across participants without the need for a central authority.
3. **Consensus Algorithms:**

   - Implement consensus algorithms such as Paxos or Raft to ensure that different nodes in a distributed system agree on the order of events.
4. **Message Queues:**

   - Use message queues like Apache Kafka or RabbitMQ to asynchronously transmit financial events while maintaining their order.
5. **Hash Functions:**

   - Apply hash functions to verify the integrity of financial data across systems, ensuring that the data has not been tampered with during transmission.
6. **Merkle Trees:**

   - Employ Merkle trees for efficient verification of large datasets by comparing only the hashes of data chunks, reducing the need for extensive data transmission.
7. **Vector Clocks:**

   - Implement vector clocks to track causality and order of events in distributed systems, helping to resolve conflicts and maintain consistency.
8. **Conflict-free Replicated Data Types (CRDTs):**

   - Use CRDTs to manage distributed data structures that can be updated independently on different nodes, resolving conflicts in a mathematically guaranteed way.
9. **Eventual Consistency Models:**

   - Embrace eventual consistency models, allowing systems to be temporarily out of sync but converging to a consistent state over time.
10. **Delta-based Replication:**

    - Transmit only the changes (deltas) to the financial data, reducing the amount of data that needs to be synchronized between systems.
11. **Causal Consistency Models:**

    - Apply causal consistency models to ensure that operations are applied in a causally ordered manner, maintaining logical dependencies between events.
12. **Time Series Databases:**

    - Utilize time series databases for efficient storage and retrieval of financial data, especially when dealing with large volumes of time-stamped information.

These algorithms and data structures help in managing the complexities of aligning financial data across asynchronous systems, ensuring consistency, reliability, and security in financial transactions and processes.

Comment: Answers generated by AI are not permitted on SO.

Comment: @LTyrone I'm sure there are rules for this sort of thing at SO. My gut reaction to AI answers is they have no place here. Then, your reply makes me realize I don't really mind an AI response to a legitimately unanswered question (mine) after 7 years... And I appreciate some input for research.